# Can an app prevent a user from switching to other apps (on android / iOS) with relevant permission?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, mobile

Is it possible to build an app that can run on either iPhone or Android that in certain situations prevents the user from switching to any other applications when it is being run?

Essentially locking the user into only being able to use this particular app?

Comment: >Is it possible to build an app that can run on either iPhone or Android ?
Opt hybrid app development environment like xamarin,Ionic,React Native etc..
>that in certain situations prevents the user from switching to any other applications when it is being run?
Override on backPressed functionality and implement your stuff for Android, am not sure about IOS.Coming other buttons in Android like and Home and Recent it difficult to invade home screen behaviour.

Comment: Correct - Have I worded this oddly?

Comment: If u have a requirement handling screens like display and hide remotely on particular time or day u can use Firebase Remote config - https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/android

Comment: Not in iOS for sure unless the device is jailbroken.

Comment: On iOS, if your app is an "assessment" app (ie like a test) then you can get a special entitlement from Apple that allows your app to lock the device to your app for a period to prevent cheating.